# Self Organized Maps (SOM) neighborhood and weight updates

Tags: som

I am studying Self Organized Map (SOM) in the Neuron Nets field. So I have 2 questions:

1) Why neighborhood size is decreasing?
2) why not update just the winner? What would happen in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

The power of the SOM is to create a neural network that will be displayable and human readable, so:

1) The neighborhood size is decreased in order to get some stability in the algorithm increasing the iterations.

2) The mean of updating also the neighborhood is to create the **map** (that will be displayable) where near units have similar weights. If you update only the winner unit, the **map**  will be not created since similar units will be left scattered in the map.